# Terminal cd .. TAB does not add slash

Tags: terminal, big-sur, zsh

When using the terminal to navigate through my files I was used to be able to type

cd .. TAB where the TAB would add the / at the end of the .. and I could just continue typing. Now, on big sur, this does not work anymore. When I type cd .. and TAB the screen just flashes once and that's it, I always have to type the /

Can anybody help how to get the old behavior?

My .zshrc file

```
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Comment: Does this help? –https://superuser.com/q/277019, https://stackoverflow.com/q/564648

Comment: Which shell are you using (bash or zsh)? Does it happen with all directories or only some?

Comment: zsh, it happens with all directories

Comment: Did you have any custom zsh settings before or after the update? Can you add your .zshrc file?

Comment: Added the .zshrc file

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/277019/zsh-parent-directory-completion solved it. The answer was out there but I did the wrong search. Maybe this question helps users who search the way I did. Thanks!

Comment: @almo If you no longer need an answer, then please close your question, so it doesn't stay in the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3):

Zsh doesn't consider `.` or `..` to be useful completions by default. For example `cd .`<kbd>Tab</kbd> offers hidden directories but not the special directories `.` and `..`. This is a difference from bash.

You can enable `.` and `..` as completion by configuring the [`special-dirs` completion style](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-special_002ddirs_002c-completion-style). This requires the “new” completion system, i.e. with a call to `compinit` in your `.zshrc` (possibly via some zsh configuration framework).

```
zstyle -e ':completion:*' special-dirs true
```

Or, to complete `..` but not `.`:

```
zstyle -e ':completion:*' special-dirs ..
```